# Adding classes, preventing changing indexes from affecting data

Tags: python, dictionary, operator-overloading

I have a class `K()` that has an `__add__()` method that works as follows

```
d_1 = K(dict(a=3, b=5), dict(b=45,c=23))
d_2 = K(dict(a='three',b='two'), dict(b='wa',c='wo'))
>>d = d_1 + d_2
>>d == K({'a': 3, 'b': 5}, {'b': 45, 'c': 23}, {'a': 'three', 'b': 'two'}, {'b': 'wa', 'c': 'wo'})
True
```

However, if I change some data

```
d_1['c'] = 'apples'
d_2['c'] = 'oranges'
```

and check again...

```
>>d == K({'a': 3, 'b': 5}, {'b': 45, 'c': 23}, {'a': 'three', 'b': 'two'}, {'b': 'wa', 'c': 'wo'})
False
```

The changing data has affected the original addition method. I've tried using .copy() to create copies of the variables we're adding, and use those- however I haven't had any luck...

```
def __add__(self, other):
    scopy, ocopy = self.copy(),other.copy()
    slist,olist = [],[]
    for x in scopy.list_of_dictionaries_from_init:
        self_temp.append(x)
    for i in other_copy.list_of_dictionaries_from_init:
         temp.append(i)
    return K(*(self_copy.list_of_dictionaries_from_init + olist))
```

This just outright doesn't work

I'm not sure how to make this work with copies

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your `copy` method is presumably just making a new list with the same dicts. When you copy a collection whose elements are themselves mutable collections, they don't get copied.

If you want to copy "all the way down", use the [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) function. For example, you can change your own `copy` method to call `deepcopy`. (And probably your `__init__` method as well.)

For example, maybe something like this:

```
def copy(self):
    return K(copy.deepcopy(self.list_of_dictionaries_from_init))
```

---

Meanwhile, your `add` method doesn't make any sense. You create `slist` and `olist` lists, but then you try to append to `self_temp` and `temp` lists, and then you try to use `self_temp` as if it were a `K` instance instead of a list. If you've got a `copy` method, it may be simpler to first define `__iadd__`, and then define `__add__` in terms of it:

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    self.list_of_dictionaries_from_init += other.list_of_dictionaries_from_init

def __add__(self, other):
    self_copy = self.copy()
    self_copy += other
    return self_copy
```